# Is there a way to get the number of hits for a filter without returning all the results of the filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

Using elastic-search, I am trying to use filters to count the number of links in two associated models.

I have Questions which has_many votes.

I have a mapping for votes, which indexes question id of each vote, and am doing

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/votes/_search -d '{query : {"constant_score" : {"filter" : { "term" : {"question_id" : 5} }, "boost" : 1.0 } }}'
```

The problem is that this returns all the results. Is it possible to simply grab a count instead?

Comment: isn't that the idea of facets? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `search_type=count` to your query string:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/votes/_search?search_type=count -d '{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : { "term" : {"question_id" : 5} }
        } 
    }
}'
```

That said, as @phoet suggested, you may want to use facets instead.

For example, for top 10 questions:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/votes/_search?pretty=1&search_type=count'  -d '
{
   "facets" : {
      "votes" : {
         "terms" : {
            "field" : "question_id"
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

Or for just question_id 5:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/votes/_search?pretty=1&search_type=count'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "constant_score" : {
         "filter" : {
            "term" : {
               "question_id" : 5
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "facets" : {
      "votes" : {
         "terms" : {
            "field" : "question_id"
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

Comment: How would you append the search_type=count if I'm using tire to access elastic-search?

Comment: @RazorStorm [search_type count queries](https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/100) is not supported yet, workaround noted in issue is set size 0.